# Package Extraction - Windows cannot open the folder

Tags: packages, package-designer

I am trying to inspect a package created by the package designer. I extract the zip file into my temp folder ok, but when I open that extracted folder and try to extract the inner `package.zip` package, I keep getting the Windows error

> Windows cannot open the folder.
>
> The Compressed (zipped) Folder 'C:\Temp\xxxxxxxx\package.zip' is invalid.

I have tried re-downloading the package from Sitecore, but I get the same error.

[image]

Comment: Which software you are using to unzip file? Many a time I faced such issue  with Winzip. So i always use WinRar and it works fine.

Comment: @aruntiwari I'm using the built-in functionality in Windows 10.

Comment: Had similar issue and `7zip` helped me with it. It's fast and it's free

Comment: Is it a large package? I've no problem on Windows 10 browsing the packages created with Sitecore using the built in functionality. Might be worth trying different software I use http://www.7-zip.org/

Comment: @WesleyLomax no, not a particularly big package - only 2 MB! Not had a problem doing this until today. I will try 7zip.

Comment: sometimes the file name is the issue try to rename it to something shorter and use alphabetical characters only

Answer (score 1):

In truth, I don't know why Windows 10 can unzip some Sitecore packages, but not others. For the ones that don't work in Windows, [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) seems work fine.

Another thing I have found is that some packages can contain very deeply nested folder structures with file paths over the Windows limit (260 characters). In cases where the package contains file paths *close* to the windows limit, extracting the package to a less deep folder on your computer can help e.g. `C:\temp`.

Comment: For Windows 10, you can actually work around this archaeological relic. https://www.howtogeek.com/266621/how-to-make-windows-10-accept-file-paths-over-260-characters/

Comment: @MarkCassidy is the original error I saw related to path lengths then, do you think?

Comment: Not entirely sure. Normally I would think your AppPool lacks necessary access to the temp folder, but then all your packages would fail - not just some. I think 7-Zip works using TEMP as a temporary folder while uncompressing; Windows built-in uses something in your AppData (so something like \windows\users\mdresser\appdata - which makes for a much longer path length.

Answer (score 0):

If running to the issue with Windows 10. Try the tar command in PowerShell (for instance) with

```
tar -xzvf .\package.zip
```

This will bypass the file name length restrictions